# Add a specific column of entire data from the backup table to the main table-specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update the main table-specific   column(barcode1,endcodingtype1,barcode2,endcodingtype2) from the backup table-specific column(barcode1,endcodingtype1,barcode2,endcodingtype2) in the SQL server.

Specific Column list:

1. barcode1
2. endcodingtype1
3. barcode2
4. endcodingtype2

Backup table of the main table: Table1

| GUID | AccountNumber | barcode1 | endcodingtype1 | barcode2 | endcodingtype2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90F66A1Q-4VA2-C036 | 747674 | PRODUCT | ABC-2 | PRODUCT | ABC-2 |
| 71S97B6B-3NH2V871 | 125668 | MFG | ADC-6 | MFG | ADC-6 |
| 63L97H0B-2BG2C456 | 988477 | MFG | ADE-5 | MFG | ADE-5 |
| . | . | . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . | . | . |
| N | N | N | N | N | N |

Main table: Table2

| GUID | AccountNumber | barcode1 | endcodingtype1 | barcode2 | endcodingtype2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90F66A1Q-4VA2-C036 | 747674 | PRODUCT | ABC-2 | PRODUCT | ABC-2 |
| 71S97B6B-3NH2V871 | 125668 | MFG | ADC-6 | MFG | ADC-6 |
| 63L97H0B-2BG2C456 | 988477 | MFG | ADE-5 | MFG | ADE-5 |
| . | . | . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . | . | . |
| N | N | N | N | N | N |

Note: N = N number of records.

Comment: I have tried the below way to update specific columns but it's not working.

UPDATE table2
SET table2.barcode1 = table1.barcode1, 
table2.endcodingtype1 = table1.endcodingtype1,
table2.barcode2 = table1.barcode2, 
table2.endcodingtype2 = table1.endcodingtype2
FROM table1,table2
WHERE table1.GUID = table2.GUID;

Comment: Why didn't that work? it looks alright. Also, you should add the info to the question, not comment

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be related to the JOIN condition and how you reference the columns in your SQL update statement. To update specific columns in table2 with values from table1, you can try like this:

```
UPDATE table2
SET
    table2.barcode1 = table1.barcode1,
    table2.endcodingtype1 = table1.endcodingtype1,
    table2.barcode2 = table1.barcode2,
    table2.endcodingtype2 = table1.endcodingtype2
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.GUID = table1.GUID;
```